# How to have two affiliations for one author?

Tags: elsarticle, author

Have a problem with the third author. could you please check that and let me know how can I fix that small typo?

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}


%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}




%\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers,super}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}


\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage{calc,ragged2e}
\hyphenation{gauss-ian}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}




\journal{MSSP}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}
    
    
        
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{Prediction ofthrative Study} 
        
        %\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on %\href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}
        
        %% Group authors per affiliation:
        % \author{Elsevier\fnref{myfootnote}}
        % \address{Radarweg 29, Amsterdam}
        % \fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}
        
        %% or include affiliations in footnotes:
        
    
        \author[mymainaddress]{Toddrkfffffhd}
        \author[mysecondaryaddress]{Farderzd\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
        \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}\ead{s1d32@studendedud}
        \author[mythirdaddress]{Rdais Kd}
        \author[myfourthaddress]{}
        \author[mysecondaryaddress]{Pidzuko}
        \author[mymainaddress]{Mgdafoszyk}
        \address[mymainaddress]{InstidFluid Fdhinery, Poh nces, dsk, Podd}
        \address[mysecondaryaddress]{Gddity of Tecogy, Faculty dtronics, Telecons and datics, Gk, Pddd}
        \address[mythirdaddress]{Compotelogies dence, Sabanci da, Pendd06, Inbul, dy}
        \address[myfourthaddress]{College of Aedl Enring, Natdvedy ofences ology, dd, Padn}



        \begin{abstract}
        
        
\noindent Plain weavefgsdgsdfsdf

        
        \end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need all those packages for this simple question?

Comment: No it is just for a small part I did not want to remove just copy it. By the way my question is not the packages

Comment: Additionally your question is answered in the manual for the `elsarticle` class. There are literately examples of multi affiliations in the manual. On my version of the manual it is on page 4.

Comment: `\author[mythirdaddress,myfourthaddress]{Rdais Kd}`works. But, please, *minimal* working examples.

Comment: @ingmar Thank you. This is what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first comment about your preamble. You're using `elsarticle`, so your paper will be submitted to some journal.

They surely don't want to see *any* layout customization. So, start with removing

```
geometry fullpage setspace fancyhdr sectsty float indentfirst changepage
```

Now have a look at what remains:

1. you load `caption` three times with contradicting options; remove these calls and just leave `subcaption`; also remove the `\captionsetup` setting;
2. `epsfig` and `latexsym` only exist because 30 year old document may need them; remove them;
3. loading `graphics`, just use `graphicx`;
4. `rotating` is loaded twice
5. `color` and `xcolor` are loaded a total of 4 times; loading both is anyway nonsense;
6. `lineno` and `hyperref` are loaded several times and almost always together for no apparent reason; note that `hyperref` should be loaded last, except for a few cases;
7. `\linespread{1}` is useless;
8. using `\mycaption` and `\myfootnote` to override what the class does with captions and footnotes is a big advance towards rejection of the paper;
9. instead of hand-defining `\degrees`, why not use `\qty{32}{\celsius}`?
10. do you really use `\scalemath`?

Now look at the proposed version, but, for your own sanity, *do remove* what you don't use in the document.

How to specify two addresses for one author? Specify both keys in the optional argument:

```
\author[mythirdaddress,myfourthaddress]{Rdais Kd}
```

Full code.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}

% general packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{natbib} % elsarticle uses it anyway

% tables and friends
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

% special packages
\usepackage{lineno}

% hyperref
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% settings
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\hyphenation{gauss-ian}

% personal commands
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

% special for elsarticle
\journal{MSSP}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Prediction ofthrative Study} 

\author[mymainaddress]{Toddrkfffffhd}
\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Farderzd\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}\ead{s1d32@studendedud}
\author[mythirdaddress,myfourthaddress]{Rdais Kd}
\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Pidzuko}
\author[mymainaddress]{Mgdafoszyk}
\address[mymainaddress]{InstidFluid Fdhinery, Poh nces, dsk, Podd}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{Gddity of Tecogy, Faculty dtronics, Telecons and datics, Gk, Pddd}
\address[mythirdaddress]{Compotelogies dence, Sabanci da, Pendd06, Inbul, dy}
\address[myfourthaddress]{College of Aedl Enring, Natdvedy ofences ology, dd, Padn}

\begin{abstract}
Plain weavefgsdgsdfsdf
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I do not think in our engineering journals editor reject because of these since we are not expert in latex. They will edit themsves after publication